# Intuitive understanding of the matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Is it accurate to say that a matrix $M(T)$ of the linear map $T:V\to W$ encodes the linear map into a series of numbers by showing how the linear map applied to the basis vectors of $V$ can be expressed as basis vectors of $W$? Is this a healthy way to imagine and intuit the matrix of a linear map?

Comment: @Bye_World It doesn't matter whether $T$ is surjective - you don't have to use *all* the basis vectors of $W$.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I misinterpreted that part.  You are exactly correct @orange_juice.

Comment: Although my doctorate is in mathematics rather than medicine, I think I can confidently say that your health is unlikely to be adversely affected by your mathematically unimpeachable  line of thought, but I would recommend you to think of your linguistic health by eschewing the absurd neologism "intuit" ("imagine" is all you need to say). $\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: Great guys, thanks! And @RobArthan, certainly not a neologism http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intuit ;)

Comment: Lexicographers would go out of business if they didn't keep populating their dictionaries with neologisms! "intuit" is fairly absurd because "intuition" is not an action and for what we do when we form an intuition, there are words like "understand" or "imagine" or "empathize" or "internalize" or ... that do a much better job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a bit of a more fleshed-out version of what you're saying, from my perspective.

What does it mean to take a basis of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$? It means that you identify each vector $v \in V$ uniquely with a tuple $(v_{1},\ldots,v_{n})$ of *components*. Now, linear maps work directly with your vector space. Consider the linear map "rotate anticlockwise by $\pi/2$" in the plane. The map picks up an arrow (or however you prefer to think of a vector) and physically rotates it round.

On the other hand, we can identify the plane with $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ via the standard basis, and then the *rotation matrix* $$R=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$
tells you how to change the *components* of your vector. If you picked a different basis, then your components would change differently. Precisely, if you change your basis with the matrix $P$, then your new transformation matrix would be $$R'=P^{-1}RP$$

In summary, linear maps change your *vectors*, while matrix multiplication changes your *components*.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's a great way to think about it.

The matrix is like the minimal information that you need to write down in order to fully specify the linear transformation.